# Can't access to a Dataset on Azure Machine Learning with SparkPool

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

Can't access to a Dataset on Azure Machine Learning with SparkPoolRecently we added a Synapse SparkPool to a Machine Learning to use it as "Compute / Attached computers".

When we use a Dataset to connect to Azure Storage Datalake Gen2 we have the following error:"Resolving access token for scope "https://storage.azure.com/.default" using identity of type "MANAGED". No identity was found on compute."

Ex of the Dataset use:ds = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, "XXXXXXXX")

If we don't use a Dataset and instead we connect directly to Azure Storage Data Lake Gen2 in the Notebook using the same compute instance (Spark Pool) the job executes succefully.

Ex of the direct connection:%%pysparkSTRUCTURED_PATH = 'abfss://curated@xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net'df_xxxxxx = spark.read.load(STRUCTURED_PATH+'/xxxx/xxxx.snappy.parquet', format='parquet')

Connect succefully to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of ML version problem,

As per the [Ms_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?tabs=cli) try this code:

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

# ADLS_gen2: 'abfss://<Container_name>@<Storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<file>'
# datastore1: 'azureml://datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<path>/<file>'
path_1 = '<Use your path>'

my_data1 = Data(
    path=path_1,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE,
    description="<description>",
    name="<name>",
    version="<version>"
)

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data1)
```